# 'ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling' in flask(python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, flask, pickle

I have tried using pickle in Flask(python 2.7) but when I run the Flask script I got an error `ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling`. I have used RandomForestClassifier object to predict the request.I have attached my code below.Unable to solve this error from two days.Any help is appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib



my_random_forest = pickle.load(open("iris_rfc.pkl", "rb"))
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def make_predict():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    predict_request = [[data['sl'], data['sw'], data['pl'], data['pw']]
    predict_request = np.array(predict_request)
    y_hat = my_random_forest.predict(predict_request)
    output = [y_hat[0]]`enter code here`
    return jsonify(results=output)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The reason seems to be a library version mismatch. The random forest classifier model was certainly generated with another sklearn version with a newer numpy version. Updating your libraries (numpy, etc.) should solve the problem.

The same behavior was reported by user drishit96 [ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling only on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075045/valueerror-non-string-names-in-numpy-dtype-unpickling-only-on-aws-lambda)

Answer (score -3):

I think the `open("iris_rfc.pkl", "rb")` is not necessary.

Try:

```
my_random_forest = pickle.load(path_to_iris_rfc.pkl)
```

Comment: The module pickle expects a file object, with `read()` and `readlines()` methods.