# ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling only on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, aws-lambda, pickle, boto3

I am using `pickle` to save my trained ML model. For the learning part, I am using `scikit-learn` library and building a `RandomForestClassifier`

```
rf =  RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,  max_depth=20, 
min_samples_split=2,  max_features='auto', oob_score=True, 
random_state=123456)
rf.fit(X, y)

fp = open('model.pckl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(rf, fp, protocol=2)
fp.close()
```

I uploaded this model on S3 and I am fetching this model using `boto3` library in AWS Lambda.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = 'mlbucket'
key = 'model.pckl'
download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
f = open(download_path, 'rb')
model = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

However, I am getting `ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling` error at this line: `model = pickle.load(f)`

Here's the log:

```
START RequestId: 3d8a1263-1e3c-11e8-8bdb-03c0ef524c0e Version: $LATEST
non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling: ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/function.py", line 31, in handler
  model = pickle.load(f)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
  return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
  dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1223, in load_build
  setstate(state)
ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling
```

I am using `python 2.7` on both local machine as well as AWS Lambda. The weird part is that the `pickle.load()` is working fine on my local machine.
I have used this code to test `pickle` on my local machine:

```
with open('/home/Documents/model.pckl', 'rb') as f:
    rf = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the library version mismatch.

The libraries that I uploaded on AWS Lambda after zipping (numpy, scipy, etc.) were of the latest version, whereas the libraries on my local machine were older. 
As soon as I updated the libraries on my local machine, built the pickle objects and updated them on S3, lambda started working fine.

So, it turns out that the versions of not only python, but also the libraries do matter when pickling objects.